# Finding minima and maxima of a function with python sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I need to find the minima and maxima of the same function within the following interval:  `= 4 − 100^2 + 10^ − 2` in the interval [-1,1].

I got a hint that the solution of the first derivative may appear as complex roots though they are actually not,  due to the limitation of using a symbolic library, and to ignore the imaginary part lower than `1×10−15` and take the absolute value of roots to make it real.

I wrote this code:

```py
import sympy as sp
x=sp.symbols('x')

# Writing the expression
y=x**4 - 100*x**2 + 10*x - 2

# first derivative
diff1=sp.diff(y,x,1)
# Second derivative
diff2=sp.diff(y,x,2)

# solution of first derivative
soln=sp.solve(diff1)

# Finding real solution within interval
soln1=[]
for i in range(len(soln)):
  # Checking imaginary solutions
  if sp.im(soln[i])!=0:
    continue
  # Checking solutions within range 0 to 1
  elif soln[i].evalf()>=-1 and soln[i].evalf()<=1:
    soln1.append(soln[i])
  else:
    continue


# Finding the maximum and minimum value

if len(soln1)>0:
  for k in range(len(soln1)):
    # Checking if soln1[k] corresponds to maxima
    if diff2.subs(x,soln1[k])<0:
      max_pt=soln1[k]
      # Evaluating the maximum value
      max_val=y.subs(x,soln1[k]).evalf()
      print(f'The maximum value of the function at {max_pt} is {max_val}')
    # Checking if soln1[k] corresponds to manima
    elif diff2.subs(x,soln1[k])>0:
      min_pt=soln1[k]
      # Evaluating the minimum value
      min_val=y.subs(x,soln1[k]).evalf()
      print(f'The mimimum value of the function at {min_pt} is {min_val}')
else:
  print("No maxima or minima of the function within the given range.")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d9c9732b352d> in <cell line: 17>()
     20     continue
     21   # Checking solutions within range 0 to 1
---> 22   elif soln[i].evalf()>=-1 and soln[i].evalf()<=1:
     23     soln1.append(soln[i])
     24   else:

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __new__(cls, lhs, rhs, **options)
    832             for me in (lhs, rhs):
    833                 if me.is_extended_real is False:
--> 834                     raise TypeError("Invalid comparison of non-real %s" % me)
    835                 if me is S.NaN:
    836                     raise TypeError("Invalid NaN comparison")

TypeError: Invalid comparison of non-real -7.09593646502773 + 0.e-20*I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy has a function `real_roots` for finding the real roots of a polynomial with rational coefficients. In this case the roots are returned as `RootOf` but if you want to see them as decimal approximations you can use evalf:

```
In [99]: from sympy import symbols, real_roots

In [100]: x = symbols('x')

In [101]: p = x**4 - 100*x**2 + 10*x - 2

In [102]: real_roots(p.diff(x))
Out[102]: 
⎡       ⎛   3               ⎞         ⎛   3               ⎞         ⎛   3               ⎞⎤
⎣CRootOf⎝2⋅x  - 100⋅x + 5, 0⎠, CRootOf⎝2⋅x  - 100⋅x + 5, 1⎠, CRootOf⎝2⋅x  - 100⋅x + 5, 2⎠⎦

In [103]: [r for r in real_roots(p.diff(x)) if -1 <= r <= 1]
Out[103]: 
⎡       ⎛   3               ⎞⎤
⎣CRootOf⎝2⋅x  - 100⋅x + 5, 1⎠⎦

In [104]: [r.evalf() for r in real_roots(p.diff(x)) if -1 <= r <= 1]
Out[104]: [0.050002500375075]
```

Comment: I wanted to express my deepest thanks